# Why cant i extract the cookie from the header? AngularJS + dJango

Tags: angularjs, django, cookies, http-headers, csrf

Im trying to get the cookie value from the header but it returns undefined.

Using $cookies module.

**Service:**

```
socialMarkt.factory('homeService', ['$http', function($http){

    var apiAddress = "http://server.apigoeshere.io:8000/s/first/";

    return {

        getEvents : function(params) {

            return $http.get(apiAddress, {params});
        }
    }

}]);
```

**Controller:**

```
homeService.getEvents({"page":"1"}).then(
        function(response){
            $scope.events = response.data.events;
            console.log($cookies.get('csrftoken')) //undefined;
        });
```

**Response Header**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn/19.4.5
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 22:47:55 GMT
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=HN8Zqh7dup4DnnZInd25WT25DEQ3m5rM; expires=Tue, 28-Feb-2017 22:47:55 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sessionid=39aq2f5d06ianw65vgm3hmf37ctlbj3l; expires=Tue, 15-Mar-2016 22:47:55 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
```

I cant get the csrftoken cookie. so i can use it to send post request on a django endpoint.

Comment: what version angular? Older versions didn't have `get()` method

Comment: Im using the latest version of angular. Angular 1.5.x

Comment: might try after a timeout but doubt that's  the problem. Is this a cross domain request?

Comment: it is a cross domain request. but i turned chrome security flag off to be able to do the requests. im getting the response but i cant get the cookie value nor send the X-XSRF-TOKEN header

Comment: try setting `withCredentials` and make sure it is CORS enabled on server also. You can't access cross domain cookies yourself. Doesn't appear that server is CORS enabled unless you left out a bunch of heders

Comment: CORS is off , thats why im using csrftoken to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery. and i did try withCredentials before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105060/discussion-between-andre-mendes-and-charlietfl).